# How do I get the children form table/MySQL

Tags: php, zend-framework

I've got small "tree". It has `id`, `parent` and `content`

http://pastebin.com/aix99CL0

In example I'm in 2 (id) position. I want to edit 4,5,6,7,8 automaticly and add a various content to `content'.

2 - has parent id=1,content=1/2; 4 has parent id=2, content=1/2/4. And if I put id 4 to id 3 it creates that tree with following content: 4=1/3/4, 6=1/3/4/6, 7=1/3/4/7, 8=1/3/4/8

http://pastebin.com/5yRxYDU0

How to do this in PHP? I mean only getting to children, without any missing. I don't wanna use nested set.

PSEUDOCODE:
id=3
get id 4, content .= tab[4][content].tab[4][id]
and so on...

Also I want to do this in zend framework.

**ARRAY ADDED IN SECOND POST IN REPLY TO MY POST**

Comment: Just add your really array and direct output ... your tree can be confusing

Comment: **MY TABLE STRUCTURE ADDED**
http://pastebin.com/6FdSXfyk

I can't add this in main post, so i add this here

Comment: make sqlfiddle, really not understand your scheme